# Continuity of a function using topological propositions

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to justify why the following function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is not continuous:

$$f(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             x-1 &   if & x \leq 3 \\
             \\ \frac{1}{2}(x-5) &  if  & x> 3
             \end{array}
   \right.$$
I know by analysis that it is obviously not continuous (because we are considering only usual topologies in this exercise) at $x=3$ but I haven't been able to show it using the topological propositions of "every inverse image of an open set is open" or showing it with neighborhoods although I have been trying several times. Any idea?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Try a small open interval in the range that contains the left hand limit but not the right hand limit. Or maybe vice versa. The pre-image needs to be an open set, i.e. it needs to contain a nbhd of every set it contains.

Comment: I think you can use $(2-\epsilon,2+\epsilon)$. The pre-image (inverse image) is not open, I believe.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC for giving me the idea of a general way of proving this kind of exercises. I have tried following the hint given by 311411 the open interval $(1,3)$ and I have obtained the pre-image $(2,3] \bigcup (7,11)$. Would this be OK? Thanks both again for your comments.

Comment: Since you say you use the ordinary topology, the example seems to rule out "f is continuous", yes. It is OK. (Since 3 is not an interior element of $f^{-1}(1,3).\;$)

Comment: Alright, and the pre-image of (1,3) I have computed is correct, right?

Comment: Yes, the pre-image looks right. (I didn't make 100% certain - that's too much like correcting homework for me :-) ). Also, I realized that I wrote up a brain glitch in my comment: it should have said "... of every __point__ it contains". I think you read it the right way regardless.

Comment: Ok, understood! Thank you very much.

Comment: BTW, you might like to work out the details of how the fact that the pre-image does __not__ contain a neighborhood of $x=3$ translates more-or-less directly into the logical negation of the epsilon-delta definition of continuity. I.e. you have shown $\exists \epsilon$ such that $\forall \delta \gt 0$, $\neg (|x-3| \lt \delta \implies |f(x) - 2| \lt \epsilon )$. [You might need to looks up what $\neg(p \rightarrow q)$ is equivalent to.]